# Ruby on Rails: Acts as taggable on gem, working with context in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, acts-as-taggable-on

I was wondering if someone can help me understand this part in the documentation:

> With the defined context in model, you have multiple new methods at
>   disposal to manage and view the tags in the context. For example, with
>   :skill context these methods are added to the model: skill_list(and
>   skill_list.add, skill_list.remove skill_list=), skills(plural),
>   skill_counts.

I have this:

**model**:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable # Alias for acts_as_taggable_on :tags
  acts_as_taggable_on :item
end
```

**controller**:

```
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    :user_id, :tag_list)
end
```

**view**

```
<%= f.text_field :tag_list %> <!-- wrapped in a simple_form -->
```

---

So my question is... does that mean, if I have `:items` in my model, I can replace all the `:tag_list` into `:item_list`? And just use item_list from now on? I tried this, but its not producing the same results as what I currently have... maybe I messed up somewhere, but is this "theoretically" correct?

Thanks

**BONUS**:

So eventually, if I have more than one thing that I want to tag:

```
acts_as_taggable_on :item, :more_taggable_item
```

I can have this in my strong params

```
params.require(:project).permit(
    :user_id, :tag_list, :more_taggable_item_list)
```

and then I can use it in my view:

```
<%= f.text_field :more_taggable_item_list %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If you use the default `acts_as_taggable` (or explicitly `acts_as_taggable_on :tags`) in your model, the following methods will be dynamically defined by the gem: `tag_list`, `tag_list=`, `tags`, `tag_counts`.

If you use `acts_as_taggable_on :items` instead (note the plural, as @smallbutton.com said), the following methods will be dynamically defined: `item_list`, `item_list=`, `items`, `item_counts`.

So in your case, you don't need the first `acts_as_taggable`. Only use `acts_as_taggable_on :items, :more_taggable_items`. You can then use `item_list` and `more_taggable_item_list` in your controllers and views, instead of `tag_list`.

---

PS: for reference, see how [`acts_as_taggable` is defined](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb#L15) in the gem:

```
# This is an alias for calling <tt>acts_as_taggable_on :tags</tt>.
def acts_as_taggable
  acts_as_taggable_on :tags
end
```

The [method generation](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable/core.rb#L15) is a bit more complex, but basically it loops over your `acts_as_taggable_on` parameters, and define the methods with them:

```
# Loop over [:items, :more_taggable_items]
tag_types.map(&:to_s).each do |tags_type|
  tag_type = tags_type.to_s.singularize # 'item', 'more_taggable_item'
  # ...

  taggable_mixin.class_eval <<-RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
    # Define item_list, more_taggable_item_list
    def #{tag_type}_list
      tag_list_on('#{tags_type}')
    end

    # ...
  RUBY
end
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have to use the plural form, as in the docs. So `:items` instead of `:item` and `:more_taggable_items` instead of `:more_taggable_item`. Rails offers a lot of functionality to use for gems when it comes to creating proper naming convetions and good gems make use of this.

```
# model
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable_on :items, :more_taggable_items
end

# params
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(
    :user_id, :item_list, :more_taggable_item_list)
end

# view
<%= f.text_field :item_list %> 
<%= f.text_field :more_taggable_item_list %>
```